# Is it possible to write an algorithm that takes the binary tree T and returns an integer value that represents the height of T

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

So I'm currently reading Data Structures and Algorithms in Java Sixth Edition and one of the exercises in the book says:

> Write algorithm that takes the binary tree T and returns an integer
>   value that represents the height of T. Recall that the height of a
>   binary tree is the number of edges between the tree's root and its
>   furthest leaf. For example, the following tree is of height 3:

The tree looks like this:

```
                           A
                          / \
                         B   C
                        / \   \
                       D   E   F
                                \
                                 G
```

Now if anyone can give some pointers on how I should start it that would be fantastic because at the moment I'm struggling
with this exercise.

Thank You so much in advance.

Edit: I apologise, I completely forgot to put my pseudocode, here it is:

```
Algorithm Total_Height (L_subtree, R_subtree, root)
Total_Height (root) {
    If (root == null)
        Return – 1
    Return max (Total_Height( root-> L_subtree), Total_Height (root-> R_subtree))
}
```

Any remarks or improvements that can be made to this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As for the "is it possible?": yes it definitely is. To start with that I'd suggest reading up on tree traversal algorithms and tutorials on binary trees. There are a lot of them on the net.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please visit [ask] on how to ask answerable questions. Also please include your current solution, how and why it fails, any errors and stacktraces you get as well as a [mre] of your current problem.

Comment: Have a look at [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm. It will give you some thoughts.

Comment: One way to solve this would be to recursively calculate the subtrees' heights, use the higher value and add 1. Leafs would have a height of 0 so that's where recursion ends. (Example: from D=0, E=0 you get B=1, from G=0 you get F=1 and thus C=2, now from B=1 and C=2 you get A=3).

Comment: You have the pseudo-code, you just need to translate it to Java.

Comment: Actually, your pseudo-code is incorrect: you should return `max (Total_Height( root-> L_subtree), Total_Height (root-> R_subtree)) + 1`: otherwise, you will always get -1.

Answer (score 0):

To get the "height" of the tree, you have to keep track of the depth you are in right now:

```
int Tree_Height(root, depth) {
    if (root == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    return max(
        Tree_Height(root.L_subtree, depth + 1),
        Tree_Height(root.R_subtree, depth + 1),
        depth
    );
}
```

You need the depth in the `max` function because at the end of the tree the result will be -1, which will propagate to the top and the overall result from the function will be -1.
If you didn't understand this explanation, try to follow the execution of your program on a piece of paper. This is always helpful when fixing bugs in recursion.